# Array in vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I wrote a following function in vbscript.

```
Function GetArray()
   Dim Array(2)
   Array(0) = "1"
   Array(1) = "2"
   GetArray = Array
End Function
```

In the page:

```
<%
   Dim IArray()
   IArray = GetArray()
%>
```

But It is not work. How can I do this?

Comment: What does "it is not work" mean? What happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Array** is a reserved word in VBScript. Just use different name:

```
Function GetArray()
   Dim MyArray(2)
   MyArray(0) = "1"
   MyArray(1) = "2"
   GetArray = MyArray
End Function
```

Also, don't declare the `IArray` as dynamic array just as ordinary variant and it will get assigned the return value of the function no matter what it's going to be:

```
Dim IArray
IArray = GetArray()
```

Comment: +1 To be clear the return type of a function is always a simple Variant   Hence when its result is assigned to a variable the variable cannot by Dimmed as an array the variable _must_ be a simple variant.  Bearing in mind that a simple variant can still contain as its value an array.

Comment: @Anthony thanks for the clarification, wasn't sure about those technical details. :)